# Option button in option group is selected

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 4 option buttons in option group and one of them is selected then button ok is clicked but I got error here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click()

If opt1 = True Then

MsgBox "Success"

End if

End Sub
```

Comment: what line is you error on and what does the error say? you may have to refer to your option button as a `yes/no` opposed to `true/false`. Also, it might be `me.opt1` that you need to use

Comment: You almost never need to read the option buttons themselves. Each button has a `OptionValue`, and the option group is assigned the value of the selected option. This is the value you usually work with.

Comment: Also, which program are you working with? Excel/Access/Word/Outlook - please remove the non-relevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your option buttons into an option group and then write your code like this:

```
Select Case Me.fTimePeriod

    Case Is = 1: sTime = "Option 1 Selected"
    Case Is = 2: sTime = "Option 2 Selected"
    Case Is = Null: sTime = "Nothing Selected"

End Select

Msgbox sTime
```

`fTimePeriod` is the name of the option group. Case 1 is the first option, Case 2 the second. Add more case statements for more options.